# How use nice-select2?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, pug

Link to the plugin https://github.com/bluzky/nice-select2/tree/master

I can't connect nice-select 2, I added css and js files from the dist folder to my project, connected them and wrote a line from the documentation. I use webpack and PUG
But I get an error that NiceSelect is not defined. What am I doing wrong?

Сonnecting css

```
link(rel='stylesheet' href=require('../assets/css/nice-select2.css'))
```

Сonnecting js

```
script(src=require('../assets/js/nice-select2.js'))
```

A line from the documentation

```
NiceSelect.bind(document.getElementById("a-select"), {searchable: true, placeholder: 'select', searchtext: 'zoek', selectedtext: 'geselecteerd'});
```

Comment: You might be trying to run code on your server in Node.js, written for Javascript running on the client in a browser. That might not work. See: [Difference between Node.js and JavaScript](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-node-js-and-javascript/). Yes, both use Javascript, but the environment is quite different.

Comment: First, check if the script is loaded in Network Tab in Dev tools, then check if you are not accessing NiceSelect before script is loaded

Answer (score 0):

`require()` is only for server-side javascript. It looks like you're wanting to load `nice-select2.js` client-side via a `<script>` element. To do that in Pug, try this instead:

```
script(src='../assets/js/nice-select2.js')
```

Which will compile to:

```
<script src="../assets/js/nice-select2.js"></script>
```

And be sure the server is correctly serving the javascript file at the path in `src`.